# npm start for react project gives error "Cannot find file: index.js"

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I have been building a project on react using vscode and when i try to start it in the browser, I keep getting the error that it cant find the file index.js, even though it is in the right folder. (Yes I have imported react and not React). I have literally paused my project for a while day because of this and its weird because i was building a smaller project earlier on the same mahine, in the same way and it worked perfectly.
But I have no idea whats going on here, I have attached the code.

I tried moving the file around, checking my lowercase, deleteing the cache memory and restarting it, deleting the node modules folder and using npm insall, etc all that stuff already on stackOverflow but nothing works.
I am just starting out with react so I'm not sure what the problem is and I've tried googling as much as I could

Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from './images/airbnb 1.png'

export default function Navbar(){
    return (
        <img src={logo} width= "40px"></img>


    )
}
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function App(){
    return(
        <h1>App component</h1>
    )
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-DOM'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: `import ReactDOM from 'react-DOM'` should be `react-dom`, lowercased. Modules published on npm are always lowercased.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new react project with "npx create-react-app" ?.

Comment: @ZacAnger THANK YOU SO MUCH! oh loll i only thought it was for the 'r' in react. I cant believe i spent a day stuck on this, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

you are trying to `import` from `react-DOM` that does not exist

Comment: Can you please edit your post explaining why this works?